# How would I go about opening another file from a .vbs file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

How would I go about opening another file from a .vbs file?

I want to run file.bat from a vbscript file, and the two files are located in folders like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9ArZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to execute your batch :

```
Option Explicit
Dim PathBatch,MyCommand
PathBatch = "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Folder1\Folder2\"
MyCommand = "CD /D " & DblQuote(PathBatch) & " & Start file.bat"
Call Run(MyCommand,1,False) 'Showing the console
'*********************************************************************************
Function Run(StrCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'A value of 0 to hide the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
'A value of 1 to show the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
    Run = Result
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like

```
set kdshell = createobject("WScript.Shell")
kdshell.Run "./folder2/file.bat",0,false
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can call your batch file from VB script this way if the batch file is in the current directory

```
      strcmd = "your_file.bat" + " " + "Arguments"

      wshshell.Run strcmd
```